# jquery single each() function for both radio and checkboxes

Tags: jquery

I'm having requirement that to check each radio button and checkbox of same div that was checked/unchecked. 
I tried this and found some what uneasy to have too separate loops.

```
 {
     $('#div1 input[type=radio]').each(...);
 }
```

and

```
 {
     $('#div1 input[type=CHECKBOX]').each(...);
 }
```

Instead of calling 2 methods, how can I use single each function for both types?

```
 {
   //Like
   $('#div input[type=radio || CHECKBOX]')
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine selectors using a comma:

```
$('#div1 :radio, #div1 :checkbox').each(...)
```

or by using [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (which I think should be marginally more efficient):

```
$("#div1").find(":radio, :checkbox").each(...)
```

Note the [:radio](http://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/) and [:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) selectors are shorthand for `input[type=...]`.